# Burn PLayable Blu-Ray

Tags: blu-ray

I want to convert and burn multiple videos to a blu-ray disc that contains a menu and is playable on any standalone BD player. What should I use? I currently have Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

Answer (score 0):

**Brasero** is pre-installed application in Ubuntu 14.04. **K3b** is another GUI Application (available to download and install) to burn CD/DVD.

To Burn **Blu-Ray** you have to install the cdrecord package. ( can be installed from PPA: [ppa:brandonsnider/cdrtools](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/cdrtools)).

For Further Information, **Visit** [Ubuntu-Help.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning)